# Auth login without use $this->request->data on cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.3

I would like to reproduce the cakephp login

if I do :

```
$this->request->data=array('User'=>array(
                'username'=>'admin',
                'password'=>'123456',
                ));
    var_dump($this->Auth->login());
    var_dump( $this->Auth->user());
```

It's working and I get

```
boolean true

array (size=6)
'id' => string '2' (length=1)
'username' => string 'admin' (length=2)
```

etc...

But if I don't use `$this->request->data`, it's not working.
According to docs: http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-AuthComponent.html#_login

> mixed $user optional null
>       Either an array of user data, or null to identify a user using the current request.

So if I use `$user` it should work but it doesn't :

```
$user=array('User'=>array(
                'username'=>'admin',
                'password'=>'123456',
                ));
    var_dump($this->Auth->login($user));
    var_dump( $this->Auth->user());
```

Thanks

Comment: If you use $this->Auth->login($user).. It will return True even Password is wrong specially in version 2.0 and greater

Comment: SO Try to use Request data

Comment: yep but i would like to check data pushed in my auth. and i can't use request data, it will erase my form data 
i try to autologin via a cookie

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use `$this->request->data` then you should also not use `$this->Auth->login()`

Try using this set of code, this should resolve your issue:-

```
$options['conditions']['username'] = 'admin';
$options['conditions']['password'] = '12345'; //if using md5 then md5('12345') 

$user = $this->User->find( 'first', $options );
if( isset( $user['User'] ) ) $this->Session->write( 'Auth', $user );
else echo "Invalid user";
```